# finding basis of a set given span

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given $W=\operatorname{span}\left(\{\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}\}| x+y=0\right)$.

To find a basis for this set, I need to find a linearly independent set of vectors such that $a_1v_1+a_1v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n=0\implies a_i=0\forall i$

I am having some trouble finding such a basis. Can anyone point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$x+y=0$ can be written as the matrix equation $$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z \\ w}=\pmatrix{0}$$

Can you solve this matrix equation?  If so, that'll give you every solution.  Then try to find a basis from that solution set.

---

**Edit:** Here's the full solution.  Note that I will be using an approach that generalizes to other matrix equations and not necessarily the *fastest* method of solving this particular problem.

So we're essentially given the augmented matrix equation $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

So we can just use our knowledge of matrix equations to find every solution to this.

First we'd want to get this into RREF.  But that's already done, so *check*.

Next we want to figure out where all the pivots are.  There's only one here:

$$\require{enclose}\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} \enclose{circle}{1} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

Now we need to assign random variable names to all coordinates corresponding to columns *without* pivots.  So the next thing we write down is:

$$\begin{cases}y=r \\ z=s \\ w=t\end{cases}\qquad r,s,t\in \Bbb R$$

Then we convert the augmented matrix back to a system of linear equations:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right) \iff x+y=0$$

Solve this for the pivot variables: $x=-y$.

Now just write down the solution set:  $$\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z \\ w} = \pmatrix{-r \\ r \\ s \\ t} = r\pmatrix{-1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0} + s\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0} + t\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1}$$

From here we can tell that $$\left\{\pmatrix{-1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0}, \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0}, \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1}\right\}$$ is a basis for this set.  And thus a basis for $W$.

Comment: i see that computing the above i get that $x+y=0$, but I don't understand what you mean by solve the equation?

Comment: @landarous If you had the matrix equation $\pmatrix{3 & 2 \\ 6 & -1}\pmatrix{x \\ y}=\pmatrix{2 \\ 3}$, how would you solve it?  What's the method you'd use (I'm not looking for you to solve it, just tell me the general method)?

Comment: multiply by the left inverse?

Comment: OK.  That does happen to be an invertible matrix, but pretend it's not.  Then what would you do?

Comment: that's the only way i'm aware to solve for unknown variables. maybe i'm forgetting something...

Comment: What about using Gauss-Jordan elimination to get the matrix into reduced row echelon form and then using [this approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466381/how-to-get-solution-matrix-from-ref-matrix/1466392#1466392)?  Surely you learned that, right?  That's the same method you use here, only $\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0\end{array}\right)$ is a particularly easy matrix (in fact it's already row reduced).

Comment: @landarous Can you figure it out from here or do you need me to completely work out this problem for you?

Comment: give me a few minutes to try to work it out first. thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I might need your help. i'm not seeing what to do after the gauss elimination into rref form. i'm not understanding what this has to do with independence?

Comment: OK.  Give me a minute to write up the process.

Comment: ah, ok. i think i get it now. i'm going to summarize, and hopefully what I'm saying is right. Using the conditions, I have to solve a matrix equation first. Then, I have to write my solution in terms of parameters (assuming my matrix isn't square). The resulting matrices will provide a basis. (is there a reason why we are ensured that this method will always give us independence?)

Comment: A square matrix might still have infinite solutions -- so you might still have parameters.  It just depends whether the matrix is invertible or not.  And if it is, you were right before that the faster way to solve that will just be to find the inverse.  But otherwise, if you always take this approach, you'll only define as many parameters as the dimension of your space (the reason would take a bit to explain) so you can be assured that the matrices you find will be linearly independent.  You can always check for linear independence afterward if you want -- but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

How can you describe the set of solutions of this linear equation? How many parameters do you need? Can you say what its dimension is?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. before i can tell the dimension, don't i first have to find the number of vectors in the basis?

Comment: You have other ways to know the dimension. For instance the number of linearly independent equations that define the vector space is equal to its codimension (use the rank-nullity theorem to see this).

Comment: thanks for the new infos but I think that's later in my course; I've never heard of "codimension" before.

Comment: It's simply the difference bets=ween the dimension of the ambient space ($4$, here) and the dimension of the subspace. Anyway if you can answer the other questions , you have a basis.

Answer (score -1):

Write the sum in terms of the constraint.

(x, y, z, w) = (-y, y, z, w) = y(-1, 1, 0, 0) + z(0, 0, 1, 0) + w(0, 0, 0, 1).

Note that the vectors after the equal sign are L.I. and generate the set. Thus, they form a basis by the Replacement Theorem.

Comment: can you elaborate? what is the replacement thm?

Comment: The replacement theorem is what allows us to say that the vectors which generate the set that are linearly independent also form a basis. You're implicitly using it when solving these kind of problems but unless you're writing proofs, you don't need to know it.