# Find a basis for the kernel of A

Tags: linear-algebra

Alright I'm having a difficulty with this one.
$$A= \pmatrix{−12 & -6 & 9 \\ 8 & 4 & -6 \\ -4 & -2 & 3 }$$
I do the row echelon form which has the first row $[-12, -6, 9]$ with everything else at zero. Can someone help me?

Comment: To get $$A= \pmatrix{−12 & -6 & 9 \\ 8 & 4 & -6 \\ -4 & -2 & 3 }$$ type `$$A= \pmatrix{−12 & -6 & 9 \\ 8 & 4 & -6 \\ -4 & -2 & 3 }$$`.  For more info on formatting your questions with MathJax see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For your actual question, that's what you're supposed to get.  Now make conclusions.  Where do you go after that to find the kernel of $A$?

Comment: I'm suppose to move it into parametric vector form -12x1-7x2+9x3 = 0. x1 would equal (7x2-9x3)/-12 correct? Can you see why I am lost? The book I have has the x1 spaces introvert for an answer on the pivots.

Comment: Try out [this approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466381/how-to-get-solution-matrix-from-ref-matrix/1466392#1466392) and let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: I figured it out, it was actually what I was doing so this was a terrible question. The answer was $$[-1/2, 1, 0]$$ x2 and $$[3/4, 0, 1]$$ x3. I just had to divide by -12. Straightforward, I apologize for this and this comment that probably did not format correctly.

Comment: No worries.  I'm glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1/2&-3/4\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This implies that
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
if and only if
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-y/2+3z/4\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}y+
\begin{bmatrix}3/4\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}z
$$
This proves
that
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}3/4\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
is a basis for $\ker A$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty straightforward to me.  The kernel will be those vectors, $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$, such that $$\begin{bmatrix}-12 & -6 & 9 \\ 8 & 4 & -6 \\ -4 & -2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-12x- 6y+ 9z \\ 8x+ 4y- 5z \\ -4x- 2y+ 3z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$.

That gives the three equations -12x- 6y+ 9z= 0, 8x+ 4y- 5z= 0, -4x- 2y+ 3z= 0.
The first equation is just 3 times the second equation.  If we multiply the third equation by 2 and add to the second equation, we have (8x+ 4y- 5z)+ (-8x- 4y+ 6z)= z= 0.  Setting z= 0 in all three equations, -12x- 6y= 0, 8x+ 4y= 0, and -4x- 2y=0.  Dividing the first of those by -6, the second by 4, and the third by -2, all reduce to 2x+ y= 0 or y= -2x.  So any such vector can be can be written as $$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}x\\ -2x \\ 0\end{bmatrix}= x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I'm too lazy to go through your answer to see where you went wrong, but the kernel should be *two* dimensional, so you must have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Oh actually I see your mistake, you wrote $8x+4y-5z=0$,  It should be $-6z$.