# Describe all solutions of Ax = 0

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-5&3&-3&-4&-2\\0&0&1&1&0&-5\\0&0&0&0&1&-3\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Describe all solutions of $Ax = 0$
>
> $x = x_2 \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\\\\\end{bmatrix} + x_4 \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\\\\\end{bmatrix} + x_6 \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\\\\\end{bmatrix}$

I'm not really sure if I'm doing this right but I put the matrix $A$ in **RREF** form to get:

Performing the matrix operations:

$1) R_1 = R_1 + 4R_3$

$2) R_1 = R_1 + -3R_2$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-5&0&-6&0&1\\0&0&1&1&0&-5\\0&0&0&0&1&-3\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

But now I'm not sure what to do to get the vectors\matrix they are wanting here?

Comment: try a general x vector with components x1,...,x6. and try to solve this underdetermined system.

Comment: They aren't asking me to solve for any components though are they? It looks as if they are asking me for 3 seperate $6 \times 1$ matrices multiplied by the components $x_2, x_4, x_6$ in which I don't understand why or *how* to obtain them

Comment: Could you provide a sample/example of one? Then I can surely solve the other two $6 \times 1$ matrixes by myself

Comment: You are essentially calculating the null space of a matrix. This tutorial might be helpful: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/null-column-space/v/null-space-2-calculating-the-null-space-of-a-matrix

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466381/how-to-get-solution-matrix-from-ref-matrix/1466392#1466392)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that there are no pivot columns for columns $2,4,6$, i.e. the columns do not have a leading $1$.

Thus, we let the following corresponding components of the vector $\vec{x}$ be free: $x_2=r,x_4=s,x_6=t$ where $r,s,t\in \mathbb{R}$.

We know solve for $x_1,x_3,x_5$ in terms of these free variables.

\begin{align}
x_1&=5r+6s-t\\
x_3&=-s+5t\\
x_5&=3t
\end{align}

Thus, all solutions to $A\vec{x}=0$ have the form 
$$\vec{x}=r\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}
6\\
0\\
-1\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
5\\
0\\
3\\
1
\end{bmatrix}:r,s,t\in\mathbb{R}$$

Note: $x_2=r, x_4=s,x_6=t$

Comment: Hannah, this answer, brilliantly explained, just brilliant.

Comment: I'm confused about something tho; why is -5,1,0,0,0,0 not valid for the r matrix?

Comment: Is my RREF incorrect? Because my RREF says that $x_1 = -5x_2 -6x_4 + x_6 \implies -5r -6s + t$

Comment: You just wrote it a different way so I don't understand what exactly is invalid about my answer?

Comment: $x_1$ is exactly $5x_2$ or $5r$ plus something else ($6x_4-x_6$). Note that this representation allows us to easily show the relationships among the components of $\vec{x}$. Look at the "rows": We have $x_1=5r+6s-t$; $x_2=r$; $x_3=0r-s+5t$ and so on.

Comment: Hannah I know, but what I'm saying is that literally you just re-wrote it, why would my answer be invalid? $3 - 2$ is the same as $-2 + 3$ and why are you treating $6x_4$ as a positive when it isn't and $x_6$ as a negative when it is a positive?

Comment: Your RREF is perfectly fine. Also, your RREF says $x_1=5x_2+6x_4+-x_6$ (Remember we are "moving" the terms to the other side for $x_1-5x_2-6x_4+x_6=0$

Comment: Oh! I'm an idiot!! Forgot about that! LOL Thanks Hannah!!

Answer (score 4):

From the already row-reduced matrix you can see that $x_2,x_4,x_6$ are free variables because the columns are missing leading $1$'s.

From row $3$, you can get $x_5-3x_6=0$, so $x_5=3x_6$
From row $2$, $x_3+x_4-5x_6=0$, $x_3=-x_4+5x_6$
From row $1$, $x_1-5x_2+3x_3-3x_4-4x_5-2x_6=0$, $x_1=5x_2-3x_3+3x_4+4x_5+2x_6$. Plug in the values of $x_5,x_3$, $$x_1=5x_2+6x_4-x_6$$
Finally turn the results into vector form:$$x = x_2 \begin{bmatrix}5\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + x_4 \begin{bmatrix}6\\0\\-1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + x_6 \begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\5\\0\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}$$