# Describe all solutions of Ax = 0 (2)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-5&-3&2\\4&-20&-12&8\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Describe all solutions of $Ax = 0$
>
> $x = x_2 \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\end{bmatrix} + x_3 \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\end{bmatrix} + x_4 \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\end{bmatrix}$

I put the matrix $A$ in **RREF** form to get:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-5&-3&2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Then I saw that $x_1 = -5x_2 + 3x_3 - 2x_4 \implies x_1 = -5r + 3s - 2t$ (because $x_1$ is not a free variable right?)

Now I don't understand how to get the rest of my rows though?

I know **-5  3 -2** will be the first row of each of my vectors respectively in order

Comment: $x_2=r$, $x_3=s$, $x_4=t$.  So $$\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4} = ?$$

Comment: Like I commented in your last question, you should read [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466381/how-to-get-solution-matrix-from-ref-matrix/1466392#1466392) if you're still having trouble with this type of problem.

Answer (score 2):

You got the reduced matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-5&-3&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
thus one equation 
$$
x_1 - 5 x_2 - 3 x_3 + 2 x_4 = 0
$$
and four unknowns. We pick the last three variables as free variables and get the general solution
$$
\begin{align}
L 
&=
\left\{ (5 x_2 + 3 x_3 - 2 x_4, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \mid x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
&=
\left\{ x_2(5 e_1 + e_2) + x_3(3 e_1 + e_3) + x_4(-2 e_1 + e_4) \mid x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
&=
\left\{ 
x_2 (5, 1, 0, 0)^T + x_3 (3, 0, 1,0)^T + x_4 (-2, 0, 0, 1)^T 
\mid x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
\end{align}
$$
where the $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial, figured it out thanks to [@Bye_World](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/137731/bye-world)

$x = r \begin{bmatrix}5\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + s \begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$